# Remove specific row in r in a dataframe

Tags: r

So, my dataframe named d and it has 5 rows and 7 columns.

One column is called DELTA_ICER

I need to remove the rows that have a DELTA_ICER <0
I tried this but doesn't work..

```
dom <-Delta_ICER<0
d <- d[!dom, ]
```

Some help please.

Thanks

Comment: d=d[d[,"DELTA_ICER"]>0,]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refer to variables within dataframes using extraction notation (e.g., with `$`). You can also do your subsetting in one line.

Here's an example:

```
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(Delta_ICER = rnorm(10), X = rnorm(10))
d[d$Delta_ICER >= 0,]
```

Result:

```
  Delta_ICER           X
2  0.1836433  0.38984324
4  1.5952808 -2.21469989
5  0.3295078  1.12493092
7  0.4874291 -0.01619026
8  0.7383247  0.94383621
9  0.5757814  0.82122120
```

And the original dataframe:

```
> d
   Delta_ICER           X
1  -0.6264538  1.51178117
2   0.1836433  0.38984324
3  -0.8356286 -0.62124058
4   1.5952808 -2.21469989
5   0.3295078  1.12493092
6  -0.8204684 -0.04493361
7   0.4874291 -0.01619026
8   0.7383247  0.94383621
9   0.5757814  0.82122120
10 -0.3053884  0.59390132
```